# How to retrieve data from ContentFragment in AEM

Tags: java, aem, sling

I think there are 2 ways retrieve data from Content Fragment.

```
ContentFragment cf = resourceResolver.resolve(cfPath).adaptTo(ContentFragment.class);

cf.getElement("summary").getContent();                      // way1
cf.getElement("summary").getValue().getValue(String.class); // way2
```

When I need to get String value, are there any difference between way1 and way2?
Which is better way?

Additional question:

When I need to get multiple values, is this only way to retrieve data from CF?

```
String[] array = cf.getElement("imagePaths").getValue().getValue(String[].class);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cf.getElement("summary").getContent();
```

getContent() is return only string and if you have node value store which describe String/Text only then recommended to use.

```
 cf.getElement("summary").getValue();
```

getValue() is returning FragmentData, which have option of multiple types to get value/values

```
cf.getElement("summary").getValue().getValue();
```

getValue() - which return Object (which you can cast) ,
getValue(T)  - which return converted type T

Nutshell - getContent() is recommended when you have only string/text type. if you have different types you can leverage getValue()